# How do I replace the contents of a Google Drive file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-api-python-client

I have a Google Drive file that has a specific file id that others rely on so they can open it. I need to replace the contents of this file (a CSV file) with new content within python. I can't seem to find any examples of how to do this, though.  I'm using Google Drive API v3 (googleapiclient). Please help.

Comment: Please see if this would help you.
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads
Instead of modifying the file, I suggest you to delete and upload a new file. Try and tell me if that works.!

Comment: Thanks, but if I do what you are suggesting, the file id will change and the other systems and processes that rely on that file id will fail. As I said, I need to change the file contents, not create a new file. I will dig deeper into that API reference you sent, though.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to create a successful test. I created a file (test.txt) in Google drive with some basic text in it. I obtained the file id by sharing a link and extracting the id from the link and then unshared it again. This python code successfully replaced the text in that file with the text in _textStream. My ultimate goal of replacing the CSV information is achieved similarly, except that the BytesIO object will be the CSV data and the _mimeType will be 'text/csv':

```
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from io import BytesIO
from apiclient.http import MediaIoBaseUpload

def gauthenticate():
    # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
    return service

def SaveTxtGDrive(service):
    # Fill in your own file id here:
    fileId = '1kEyXXXXXXXX_gEd6lQq'
    _mimeType = 'text/plain'
    _textStream = BytesIO(b'Here is some arbitrary data\nnew text\nAnother line\n') 
    _media = MediaIoBaseUpload(_textStream, mimetype=_mimeType,
        chunksize=1024*1024, resumable=True)
    _updatedFile = service.files().update(fileId=fileId,
        media_body=_media).execute()

def main():
    _service = gauthenticate()
    SaveTxtGDrive(_service)
    return

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    main()
```

The Google API documentation sure is opaque and v3 has few examples in python! Obviously, the Drive API key must be set up and the API enabled for Google Drive for this to work. I simply followed the error messages that popped up to enable all of that. I hope this helps someone else.